# Add series of images reference to array

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I am working on existing UWP (Universal Windows Platform), I have following code,

UWP:

```
<Image x:Name="img1" ... />
.
.
<Image x:Name="img100" ... />
```

C#:

```
private BitmapImage empty = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\\img\empty.png"));

private void Init()
{
    img1.Source = e;
    .
    .
    img100.Source = e;
}
```

It works. But I want to make some refactoring so I can put it in Array of Image object like:

```
var imageInitList = new Image[100];

imageInitList[0] = img1;
.
.
imageInitList[99] = img100;
```

Question, how can I apply following psudo in C#? img1 ... img100 is Image type.

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    imageInitList[i] = img + i
}
```

Comment: It is still not clear to me what you want to achieve. Do you still want to declare the images in XAML or do you want to create them in code? And where do you want to set the source for the images?

Comment: @MartinZikmund The images are already declared in xaml from previous code with default images, all these images get change default image depending on some status. I want to put them in array so I can update process on eash of them depending on status, but first of all how can i put img1 object til img100 object in array. it is is easy by doing it manully but i want to loop these images in put them in array. hope that clear you question if so please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring a big number of `Image` elements in XAML sounds like a job better suited for a code-behind file or a layout control like `GridView` or `ListView`. However, if you insist on keeping the declaration in XAML, you can use the `FindName` method to query a `x:Name`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    imageInitList[i] = (Image)FindName($"img{i}");
}
```

[`FindName` is a method on `FrameworkElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement) so you can call it in the page's code-behind to get any named element in the page.

Comment: I was not aware of FindName as I new to this topic, this is exactly what I was looking for. And sure I am learning this I might change a lot later, but for now this is good enough.